# Azure with PowerShell: empty string for Identity

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-teams, powershell-5.1

I have a PowerShell script that logs into Azure and assign a group call membership to a user based on the input email address the user gave:

```
Function SetUser
{
    $script:user = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the user's email address"    

    Write-Host "You set the email address as '$user'." -ForegroundColor yellow
}

Function Assigndelegate($user)
{
    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($user)
    New-CsUserCallingDelegate -Identity $identity -Delegate $user -MakeCalls $true -ReceiveCalls $true -ManageSettings $false 
} -ArgumentList $user
    while ($job.State -eq 'Running') {
        Write-Host "Connecting to Azure..."
        Wait-Job -Job $job
    }
    $result = Receive-Job $job

    (Get-CsUserCallingSettings -Identity $user).Delegators | ft -Property Id, MakeCalls, ReceiveCalls, ManageSettings
}


Connect-MicrosoftTeams

$script:identity = "user@contoso.com"
SetUser
Assigndelegate $user
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is an empty string.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-CsUserCallingDelegate], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,New-CsUserCallingDelegate
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

What I understand is that it cannot read the variable $identity, but I don't see the reason why: I tried also with the "$global:" prefix to see it works, even though that would not be ideal as this changes later, got the same error. If I directly add the value of this variable, it works.

If I define Identity in the same name in the 'param' and 'ArgumentList' the error changes to:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is an empty string.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-CsUserCallingDelegate], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,New-CsUserCallingDelegate
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
 
Get-CsUserCallingSettings : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.
At line:36 char:42
+     (Get-CsUserCallingSettings -Identity $user).Delegators | ft -Prop ...
+                                          ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-CsUserCallingSettings], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-CsUserCallingSettings
```

UPDATE:

After Updating the argument list, I still get the error:

```
#Set the user
Function SetUser
{
    $script:user = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the user's email address"    

    Write-Host "You set the email address as '$user'." -ForegroundColor yellow
}

Function Assigndelegate($user, $identity)
{
    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($user, $identity)
    New-CsUserCallingDelegate -Identity $identity -Delegate $user -MakeCalls $true -ReceiveCalls $true -ManageSettings $false 
} -ArgumentList @($user, $identity)


    while ($job.State -eq 'Running') {
        Write-Host "Connecting to Azure..."
        Wait-Job -Job $job
    }
    $result = Receive-Job $job

    #(Get-CsUserCallingSettings -Identity $user).Delegators | ft -Property Id, MakeCalls, ReceiveCalls, ManageSettings

}


Connect-MicrosoftTeams

$script:identity = "user@contoso.com"
SetUser
Assigndelegate $user, $identity
```

UPDATE II

Based on the idea recommended I simplified the script:

```
Function SetUser
{
    $script:user = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the user's email address"    

    Write-Host "You set the email address as '$user'." -ForegroundColor yellow
}

Function Assigndelegate($user, $identity)
{
 Write-Output $identity

}

$script:identity = "user@contoso.com"
SetUser
Assigndelegate $user, $identity
```

It gives no results apart from:

```
"You set the email address as '$user'." -ForegroundColor yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

The Start-Job cmdlet starts a process in a separate session, so none of the scopes (local, script or global) are visible to the script block it executes. The only way around this is to add identity as a parameter in your script block and pass it explicitly, i.e:

```
Function SetUser
{
    $script:user = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the user's email address"    

    Write-Host "You set the email address as '$user'." -ForegroundColor yellow
}

Function Assigndelegate($user, $identity)
{
    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        param($user, $identity)
        New-CsUserCallingDelegate -Identity $identity -Delegate $user -MakeCalls $true -ReceiveCalls $true -ManageSettings $false
    } -ArgumentList @($user, $identity)

    while ($job.State -eq 'Running') {
        Write-Host "Connecting to Azure..."
        Wait-Job -Job $job
    }

    $result = Receive-Job $job

    (Get-CsUserCallingSettings -Identity $user).Delegators | ft -Property Id, MakeCalls, ReceiveCalls, ManageSettings
}

Connect-MicrosoftTeams
$script:identity = "user@contoso.com"
SetUser
Assigndelegate -user $user -identity $identity
```

Comment: updated my question after running 

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
param($user, $identity)
(...)
-ArgumentList $user, $identity
(...)
Assigndelegate $user, $identity

Comment: sorry, should have remembered the argument list needs to be specified as an array, I've amended my answer

Comment: On the top of the original error I also got:

Get-CsUserCallingSettings : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.
At line:36 char:42
+     (Get-CsUserCallingSettings -Identity $user).Delegators | ft -Prop ...
+                                          ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-CsUserCallingSettings], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException

So from this it seems the issue is with '(Get-CsUserCallingSettings -Identity $user).Delegators ' ?

Comment: If you're still getting the same error as before about $identity being empty for the New-CsUserCallingDelegate cmdlet, I'd sort this problem out first. It would be worth putting a line in with 'Write-Output $identity' to check the variable is being passed through correctly.

Have you changed the argument list to use an array - @($user, $identity) - as above?

Comment: I add UPDATE II to my question: actually removing all the MS-Teams 'noise', the function Write-Output $identity gives no values - so the script indeed fails as the variable stores nothing. Any idea why?

Comment: the script in your second update doesn't use correct syntax for calling a function - parameters aren't passed separated by commas. So in that case, you would call 'Assigndelegate $user $identity'. I'll update my answer based on your original script to include the whole lot

Comment: hi @PSrookie, any chance you could mark this as the answer or let me know why it didn't work for you?